# Overriding a property in a swift class which is defined initially in a Obj-c superclass

Tags: swift

Although I fully appreciate it's bad practice for strongly typed implementations, I have a some generic code that needs to be changed in a subclass.  The getters and setters in the obj-c code deals with *id* typed values so it is expecting more generalised values.

```
// objc
@interface A
@property NSNumber* foo;
@end

// swift subclass
class B : A {
   var foo: String?
}
```

Is there anyway to define a property is Swift so that it replaces entirely the superclass property?

The loosely typed nature of Obj-c with the (id) type allows some flexibility, that is closed down in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. You can override the property to provide different behavior, but changing the type violates OO design and thus doesn't compile.

To override a property:

```
override var foo: NSNumber! {
  get { return NSNumber(int: 5) }
  set { }
}
```

**Edit: Why does this break OO?**

The reason is that by inheriting from A, you promise to act like an A.  Imagine what would happen if you had a function like this:

```
func doStuff(obj: A) {
   print("Foo / 2: \(Float(obj.foo.integerValue) / 2.0)")
}
```

What would happen if you tried to submit an instance of `B` here? In a strongly-typed, compiled language, this can't be reconciled.  In a dynamic language, this would result in a runtime error.

I'll also mention [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming that states that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e., an object of the type T may be substituted with its subtype object of the type S) without altering any of the desirable properties of that program (correctness, task performed, etc.)

This is more of a guideline that says you shouldn't break existing behavior of methods and procedures that operate on your superclass, just because you subclassed.  But the same is true for structure, it's just the compiler enforcing this rather than being a guideline.

Comment: Thanks, just a query though, does it break OO design?  As the ability to override a property, that breaks inheritance up the chain still seems to conform.  And any interactions with b.foo would be to a string, and a.foo would be a number.  The classes are still strongly typed, and in that respect type safe.

Comment: (moved comment to my answer)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the post.  I do remember studying this a long time ago now, but it always seemed at odds with other styles of object structuring, such as extensions.  Anyhow, you have answered my question thanks, and this is tipping over into ideological programming techniques.